# Why Computed component is not re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, state, rendering, global-state

I am using `legend state` and trying to explore this. And I didn't understand why the `<Computed></Computed>` component is not re-rendering on state change.

Here is my code.

```
import {Computed, Show, useObservable} from '@legendapp/state/react'
import { useInterval } from '../utils/hooks'

function LegendStateModal() {
    const showChild = useObservable(false)
    // const text = useComputed(() => showChild.get() ? 'true' : 'false')
  
    useInterval(() => {
      showChild.set((v) => !v)
    }, 1000)
  
    return (
      <div className='flex flex-col'>
        <span>Showing child: </span>
  
        <Computed>
          <span
            className={showChild.get() ? 'text-red-900' : 'text-green-900'}
          >
            {showChild.get() ? 'true' : 'false'}
          </span>
        </Computed>
  
        <Show if={showChild}>
          <div>Child element</div>
        </Show>
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default LegendStateModal;
```

I am expecting that on every second the `showChild` state will be toggled. And after the state changed

```
<Show if={showChild}>
    <div>Child element</div>
</Show>
```

will re-rendered. Which is doing fine.

But

```
<Computed>
     <span
      className={showChild.get() ? 'text-red-900' : 'text-green-900'}
     >
       {showChild.get() ? 'true' : 'false'}
    </span>
</Computed>
```

is not.

As it should be based on documentation: [legendapp state docs](https://legendapp.com/open-source/legend-state/)

Code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/golammostafa13/explore-legend/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400072v6fk0hbcypt%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400032v6fb1ei4ag0%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400052v6fbutp1zup%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400062v6fjisv5d2v%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clmvtjr2400032v6fb1ei4ag0%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400032v6fb1ei4ag0%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmvtk1j5006d2v6faybnir1z%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400022v6f3iq39xh6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fcomponents%252FShowModal.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtk1j5006d2v6faybnir1z%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522DIRTY%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmvtjr2400062v6fjisv5d2v%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400062v6fjisv5d2v%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmvtk6xe007g2v6foq7eyvci%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtk6xe007g2v6foq7eyvci%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmvtjr2400052v6fbutp1zup%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400052v6fbutp1zup%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400042v6fsk0s462i%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtjr2400042v6fsk0s462i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clmvtjrbs0010e5ea31gd16x1%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmvtk1gk005g2v6fclhu5wso%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Answer (score 0):

The child of the `Computed` component must be a function:

```
<Computed>
 {() =>
    <span
      className={showChild.get() ? 'text-red-900' : 'text-green-900'}
      >
      {showChild.get() ? 'true' : 'false'}
    </span>
  }
</Computed>
```

Edit:

They are using a babel plugin to achieve this behaviour
https://legendapp.com/open-source/state/fine-grained-reactivity/#optionally-add-the-babel-plugin